# Как в BASH скрипте разбить команду с параметрами на несколько строк?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell

Есть строка в баш скрипте (temp.sh) которая скачивает файл:

```
wget -c http://guvm.mvd.ru/upload/expired-passports/list_of_expired_passports.csv.bz2 -O /tmp/list_of_expired_passports.csv.bz2 -U "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 YaBrowser/19.9.2.228 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
```

Как мне разбить её на строки чтобы было более читабельно, к примеру вот так:

```
wget 
-c http://guvm.mvd.ru/upload/expired-passports/list_of_expired_passports.csv.bz2 
-O /tmp/list_of_expired_passports.csv.bz2 
-U "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 YaBrowser/19.9.2.228 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
```

Попробовал сделать так:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget \ 
-c http://guvm.mvd.ru/upload/expired-passports/list_of_expired_passports.csv.bz2 \
-O /tmp/list_of_expired_passports.csv.bz2 \
-U "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 YaBrowser/19.9.2.228 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
```

но получил ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я вообще-то не знаком с `bash`, может кто подсказать как разбить на строки команду с её параметрами?

P.S. код пишу через редактирование temp.sh через notepad++ используя ftp, а запускаю используя ssh - `sh temp.sh`.

Comment: Вы уверены, что \ был действительно в конце строки?

Comment: @0xdb я поправил вопрос, может теперь будет заметно что я не так делаю, везде пишут про обратный слэш но чего-то у меня не выходит с ним ничего...

Comment: В вашем примере после `wget \\` стоит лишний пробел

Comment: Если редактируете на винде, проверьте, что сохраняете файл с правильными переводами строк. Должно быть Unix. http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/How_to_avoid_DOS_line_endings_in_Windows_tools#Notepad.2B.2B

Comment: Здесь  `wget \ ` есть ещё пробел после обратного слэша.

Comment: Пробел в конце я добавил после, ни с ним ни без него также не работает, я понял что скорей всего у меня ошибка в разрыве строки (после коммента Alexey Ten), не особо знаком с unix, вот наверстываю, сейчас почитаю попробую поправить )

Comment: @AlexeyTen пожалуйста разместите свой комментарий с правильным переходом строки в ответ, он помог!

Comment: Всем спасибо за внимание, проблема решена! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Так как я редактировал файл через notepad++ из под Windows с настройками формата строки CR LF, это и вызывало ошибку, после комментария **Alexey Ten** и указания ссылки на мануал где можно легко переключить режим в Unix (LF) тем самым приведя файл в правильный вид всё заработало без ошибок.